# Is it possible to make even columns on this wordpress theme? Link provided with ids specified

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Link for reference is here: http://www.roi-owa.com/

The sidebar column (on the right) is written like this...

```
#aside {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The main content column (on the left) and wider....is written like this...

```
#content.alpha,
#content.beta {
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: none;
}
```

The problem is that with how this theme is written...the aside column isn't contained inside a floated container with the content div...so I might be stuck. I don't want to start rewriting theme files, I just want the right column to stretch down to the height of the #content div. Not sure if its possible.

Comment: You are going to have to rewrite theme files, I'm afraid.  Is that such a bad thing?  There's nothing wrong with getting your hands dirty.  If you want to keep the original theme intact, use a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know of way for this to be done in pure CSS, since the columns know nothing about each other. However, some simple Jquery could be used.

The idea is to check the height of both and set the shorter one's height to the longer one's height. It should look something like this in jQuery:

```
var contentHeight = $("#content").outerHeight();
var asideHeight = $("#aside").outerHeight();

if ( contentHeight > asideHeight ) {
  $("#aside").height( contentHeight );
}
else {
  $("#content").height( asideHeight );
}
```